# MongoDB transaction with @NestJs/mongoose not working

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I really need your help. My MongoDB transaction with @NestJs/mongoose not working...When My stripe payment fails rollback is not working... Still, my order collection saved the data...How can I fix this issue..?

```
  async create(orderData: CreateOrderServiceDto): Promise<any> {
    const session = await this.connection.startSession();
    session.startTransaction();
    try {
      const createOrder = new this.orderModel(orderData);
      const order = await createOrder.save();

      await this.stripeService.charge(
        orderData.amount,
        orderData.paymentMethodId,
        orderData.stripeCustomerId,
      );
      await session.commitTransaction();
      return order;
    } catch (error) {
      await session.abortTransaction();
      throw error;
    } finally {
      await session.endSession();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same issue and i found that on github: [Mongo DB Transactions With Mongoose & Nestjs](https://github.com/andrechristikan/ack-nestjs-boilerplate-mongoose/issues/11)

So I think, according this issue, you have to call the `create` method of your model, like that:

```
const order = await this.orderModel.create(orderData, { session });
```

as you can see, the `Model.create` method has an overload with `SaveOptions` as parameter:

```
create(docs: (AnyKeys<T> | AnyObject)[], options?: SaveOptions): Promise<HydratedDocument<T, TMethodsAndOverrides, TVirtuals>[]>;
```

it takes an optional `SaveOptions` parameter that can contain the session:

```
interface SaveOptions {
  checkKeys?: boolean;
  j?: boolean;
  safe?: boolean | WriteConcern;
  session?: ClientSession | null;
  timestamps?: boolean;
  validateBeforeSave?: boolean;
  validateModifiedOnly?: boolean;
  w?: number | string;
  wtimeout?: number;
}
```

Please note that `Model.save()` can also take a `SaveOptions` parameter.
So you can also do as you did like that:

```
const createOrder = new this.orderModel(orderData);
const order = await createOrder.save({ session });
```

### A little further...

As i do many things that require a transaction, I came up with this helper to avoid many code duplication:

```
import { InternalServerErrorException } from "@nestjs/common"
import { Connection, ClientSession } from "mongoose"

export const mongooseTransactionHandler = async <T = any>(
  method: (session: ClientSession) => Promise<T>,
  onError: (error: any) => any,
  connection: Connection, session?: ClientSession
): Promise<T> => {
  const isSessionFurnished = session === undefined ? false : true
  if (isSessionFurnished === false) {
    session = await connection.startSession()
    session.startTransaction()
  }

  let error
  let result: T
  try {
    result = await method(session)

    if (isSessionFurnished === false) {
      await session.commitTransaction()
    }
  } catch (err) {
    error = err
    if (isSessionFurnished === false) {
      await session.abortTransaction()
    }
  } finally {
    if (isSessionFurnished === false) {
      await session.endSession()
    }

    if (error) {
      onError(error)
    }

    return result
  }
}
```

#### Details

the optional parameter `session` is in case you are doing nested nested transaction.
that's why i check if the session is provided. If it is, it means we are in a nested transaction. So we'll let the main transaction commit, abort and end the session.

#### Example

for example: you delete a `User` model, and then the user's avatar which is a `File` model.

```
/** UserService **/
async deleteById(id: string): Promise<void> {
  const transactionHandlerMethod = async (session: ClientSession): Promise<void> => {
    const user = await this.userModel.findOneAndDelete(id, { session })
    await this.fileService.deleteById(user.avatar._id.toString(), session)
  }

  const onError = (error: any) => {
    throw error
  }

  await mongooseTransactionHandler<void>(
    transactionHandlerMethod,
    onError,
    this.connection
  )
}

/** FileService **/
async deleteById(id: string, session?: ClientSession): Promise<void> {
  const transactionHandlerMethod = async (session: ClientSession): Promise<void> => {
    await this.fileModel.findOneAndRemove(id, { session })
  }

  const onError = (error: any) => {
    throw error
  }

  await mongooseTransactionHandler<void>(
    transactionHandlerMethod,
    onError,
    this.connection,
    session
  )
}
```

#### So, in short:

You can use it like this:

```
async create(orderData: CreateOrderServiceDto): Promise<any> {
  const transactionHandlerMethod = async (session: ClientSession): Promise<Order> => {
    const createOrder = new this.orderModel(orderData);
    const order = await createOrder.save({ session });

    await this.stripeService.charge(
      orderData.amount,
      orderData.paymentMethodId,
      orderData.stripeCustomerId,
    );

    return order
  }

  const onError = (error: any): void => {
    throw error
  }

  const order = await mongooseTransactionHandler<Order>(
    transactionHandlerMethod,
    onError,
    this.connection
  )

  return order
}
```

Hope it'll help.

## EDIT

Do not abuse of the `model.save({ session })` of the same model in nested transcations.
For some reasons it will throw an error the model is updated too many times.

To avoid that, prefer using model embeded methods that update and return a new instance of your model (`model.findOneAndUpdate` for example).

Comment: Best explanation I ever had... Thank you.❤️ Thank you very much for your time... This really helped me.❤️

Comment: I'm glad i could help  you ! Have fun with NestJS 

Comment: This was explanatory and wild to read <3